# Yii2: how to show different layouts depending on url route?

Tags: php, yii2, accelerated-mobile-page

I want to start using AMP (Accelerated Mobile Pages) for Google and article urls like `example.com/my-article` must also be available as `example.com/amp/my-article`, but different layout.

**Question:** How should I structure my Yii2 code to show different layouts and make url route rules for article controller? Some tips I made:

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (...) // ??
        $this->layout = 'amp';
    else
        $this->layout = 'main';

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}

public function actionView($article_slug)
{
    $model = $this->findModel($article_slug);

    if ($this->layout == 'amp')
        $path = 'amp/view';
    else
        $path = 'html/view';

    return $this->render($path, [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```

What to write in `config.php`?

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [

        // ??
        'amp/<article_slug:[\w\-]+>' => 'article/view',

        '<article_slug:[\w\-]+>' => 'article/view',
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this in before action

```
public function beforeAction($action)
{
    if (\Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam('amp')) {
        $this->layout = 'amp';
    else
        $this->layout = 'main';

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

And configure URL manager like this

```
'urlManager' => [
    'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
    'showScriptName' => false,
    'rules' => [
        '<amp>/<article_slug:[\w\-]+>' => 'article/view',

        '<article_slug:[\w\-]+>' => 'article/view',
    ],
],
```